# Send stop recording request to RTPEngine from outside current session

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, opensips

I have an Opensip / RTPEngine setup where Opensips sends a start recording request to rtpengine when callers are connected. But we have an unfortunet situation where one of the callers can disapear without sending the BYE to opensips so opensips can't send the rtpengine_delete() to rtpengine and the session is stuck and rtpengine records forever.

Is it possible to send the stop recording requset from a 3rd party lets say from a php exec() or somehow?

Comment: Have you tried using the `-o, --timeout` option of rtpengine? The answer should be along these lines, as `rtpengine` is the most natural piece of the platform that can easily detect the "no more RTP" state in the first place!

Comment: Yes I set timeout to 10sec in my config file and its not stopping.

Comment: have you solved your problem ?? I' also stuck somewhere like it !!